# Renaming stored procedure results in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

Update:
Just to make clear, I cannot revise the database itself in any way.  Can't change column names or run code first migrations, etc.  I need a pure "client" side solution

I currently have code to call a stored procedure, using code first in EF 6.1 which looks like:

```
public class LabResult
{        
    public string lr_drawn_date{ get; set; }
    public int? Patient_Code_Id { get; set; }
    public int Patient_Id { get; set; }
    public string lt_value { get; set; }
    public string lt_value_text { get; set; }
    public double lt_value_numeric { get; set; }
    public string lf_var { get; set; }
}

var idParam = new SqlParameter
     {
        ParameterName = "Patient_Code_Id",
        Value = patientId;
     };
var results = Database.SqlQuery<LabResult>("Get_Patient_Lab @Patient_Code_Id", idParam);
return results.ToList();
```

This works, but I want to change the names of the fields, for example. change lr_drawn_date to the more readable DrawnDate

I tried adding an attribute such as

```
[Column("lr_drawn_date")] 
public string DrawnDate {get; set;}
```

But this does nothing...instead, `DrawnDate` simply is empty.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: How are you creating the databases? If you are using Code First Migrations then you will have to update the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Code First, you can simply rename your object properties and run `Update-Database` command from the Package Manager Console. It will apply Entity Framework migrations to your database.